# Default JSON property if not exists using Jolt

Tags: java, json, jolt

I want to set a default value only if the JSON property not exists.

For example, below is my **Jolt spec** :

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-default-beta",
    "spec": {
      "lastName": "[empty]"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "firstName": "firstName",
      "lastName": "lastName"
    }
  }
]
```

When **input** is :

```json
{
  "firstName": "John"
}
```

the **output** is as expected :

```json
{
  "firstName" : "John",
  "lastName" : "[empty]"
}
```

On the other hand when **input** is :

```json
{
  "firstName": "John",
  "lastName": null
}
```

I'm expecting the output is same as the **input** :

```json
{
  "firstName": "John",
  "lastName": null
}
```

is there anyway to default only when property not exists regardless of it value. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all the **shift** transformation is not needed. You can use an ***isNull*** function within a modify transformation such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-default-beta",
    "spec": {
      "lastName": ["=isNull(@(1,&))", "[empty]"]
    }
  }
]
```

where

- `@(1,&)` represents the value of the current attribute, eg.
  `"lastName"`(the *ampersand* stnds for the `lastName` literal)
- if the function is able to run, then the value `null` returns directly,
  otherwise the second argument `"[empty]"` returns

Comment: Hi @vlcheong nice to help, take care